# Windbg stacktrace shows line numbers before or after macro expansion

Tags: c, macros, windbg, stack-trace

I have a C file with several macros.

The exe generated from the file crashes several times reporting events in the Windows event viewer. Upon taking a dump of the process and analyzing it using WinDbg with the correct pdb files for the symbols, we get the stacktrace and know the function which is causing the problem.

The stacktrace shows the line number of our function code which called other functions one of which led to the crash-

```
08 msvcr80!fwrite(void * buffer = 0x00000000`01ded180, unsigned int64 size =
0x1fff38, unsigned int64 count = 0x524fe123, struct _iobuf * stream =
0x00000000`00000000)+0x5f [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\fwrite.c
@ 77]
09 <function name>(void * param = 0x00000000`02d15a00)+0xb02
[<path to file> @ 1516]
```

Our function called `fwrite`, which is shown to be at line 1516. However, there is no call to fwrite at 1516. (The crash happens because the stream argument to `fwrite` is 0x0)

I was wondering if these line numbers correspond to the source file *after* the macros are expanded ? What could be the reason for a *possibly* wrong line number ?

**EDIT** : The exe here is a debug build and was compiled with optimizations disabled.

I loaded the dump again in WinDbg but also linked in the source file to WinDbg itself this time. It points to line 1516 and upon viewing that in the source from WinDbg, it points to a line where there is no call to `fwrite`. However, there is such a call a few lines above.

Comment: The most likely explanation is optimatization.  If the program crashing is an optimized build, the compiler can create very confusing line information for the generated code since there are transformations done that make the generated code very different from the original source.  In general, the preprocessor uses `#line` directives (or a proprietary equivalent) to keep the symbolic line information in sync with the source code as written, not the expanded code.

Comment: So this would mean the line numbers being shown are from an optimized version ?

Comment: That would be my guess, but it's just a guess. Since you are building the exe, you can determine whether or not that's the case.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : Please have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Well i do not have direct answer to question here :(

But i would make a COD file. `a file that maps source code to assembly code`. Then see the assembly code generated for the function of interest. Specifically related to line 1516.

Am hoping that would give a fair insight as to whats going on behind the scene. You may want to give a quick try.

You just need to turn on a compiler flag to generate COD file. More can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx)